# How to make openca-base-1.1.1 in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: openca

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and now I want to build openca-base-1.1.1. I've installed openca-tools, and using the openssl 1.0.0e. However it failed to make it. It quite confuses me. Following is what I get:

```
Build::External PERL modules

Building (openca::ac) ... Ok.
Building (openca::configuration) ... Ok.
Building (openca::crl) ... Ok.
Building (openca::crypto) ... Ok.
Building (openca::dbi) ... Ok.
Building (openca::ldap) ... Ok.
Building (openca::log) ... Ok.
Building (openca::openssl) ... ERROR::Can not build module
make[6]: *** [openca-openssl] 错误 1


Build::External PERL modules

Building (Authen::SASL::213) ... Ok.
Building (Convert::ASN1::022) ... Ok.
Building (CGI::Session::442) ... Ok.
Building (Bit::Vector::710) ... Ok.
Building (MIME::Base64::308) ... Ok.
Building (DBI::160) ... Ok.
MySQL is DISABLED
PostgeSQL is DISABLED
Building (Digest::HMAC::102) ... Ok.
Building (Digest::MD5::239) ... Ok.
Building (Digest::SHA1::212) ... Ok.
Building (libintl::perl::120) ... Ok.
Building (Net::SSLeay::136) ... ERROR::Can not build module
make[6]: *** [Net-SSLeay-1.36] 错误 1
make[5]: *** [modules] 错误 1
make[4]: *** [__install_dir] 错误 2
make[3]: *** [ext-modules] 错误 2
make[2]: *** [__install_dir] 错误 2
make[1]: *** [src] 错误 2
make: *** [__install_dir] 错误 2
```

Someone said that should patch something, I don't what happened.

Answer (score 3):

When doing ./configure add the following switch: --with-openssl-prefix=. I've got openssl built from sources and installed to /usr/local/ssl. For me this fixed froblem with openca::openssl.